# Constructive compactness for countable models?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, model-theory, constructive-mathematics, reverse-math

The compactness theorem for countable (Tarski?) models is equivalent to the weak König's lemma by a result of H. Friedman and others as noted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228389), in the context of classical logic. The weak König's lemma in constructive mathematics has been extensively studied as noted [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228468). What is the status of the *compactness theorem for countable models* itself in constructive mathematics.

One relevant paper seems to be *Moerdijk, Ieke; Palmgren, Erik. Minimal models of Heyting arithmetic. J. Symbolic Logic  62  (1997),  no. 4, 1448–1460.*

One relevant issue is the mutual relation of the following three items:

(1) compactness theorem for countable models;

(2) weak Koenig's lemma;

(3) lesser limited principle of omniscience (LLPO).

In what constructive setting are these principles equivalent? More specifically: how much of the proof of equivalence sketched in the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228389) can be retained in a suitable constructive setting, using references mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/228468)?

Comment: There are different frames for models of intutionistic logic, like kripke model, beth model and a model theory in real line. So you should specify what do you mean by countable model.

Comment: I had in mind mostly Bishop's framework, with a suitable interpretation of "countability" so as hopefully to obtain a positive result for compactness. Is there any chance of that?

Comment: I believe both the proof of compactness for countable models from WKL and the reversal are constructive, according to most definitions of the term; so my understanding is that the status of the two are identical. (But I could be wrong.)

Comment: As much as I know Bishop does not suggest any "model theoretic" framework in his book "Constructive analysis", actually it is like you work in a specific model name "standard model" in analysis like working in analysis in classical logic, without talking about models of real analysis.

Comment: The compactness theorem is a classical theorem about classical models. It would be very unusual for someone in constructive mathematics to worry about such a result. On one hand, constructivists such as Bishop avoid formalization entirely, and thus also avoid model theory. Bishop's interest, essentially, is core math only.  On the other hand, constructive metamathematics is done with alternative kinds of models that are relevant to constructive logic. The concept of a model (in the sense of classical model theory) has classical logic through and through (e.g. in the T-schema).

Comment: @Noah Schweber: in a professional context of logic, I would read "constructive" to mean something like "in intuitionistic logic", rather than the weaker informal meaning that some mathematicians use for it (e.g. "provable in ZF").

Comment: @ErfanKhaniki as far as I know Douglas Bridges (Bishop's coauthor) does have a specific axiomatisation in mind when he talks about BISH.

Comment: @katz: I would find that quite surprising. One common aspect of constructive mathematics is an avoidance of formalization, and of formal systems in general.  Sometimes logicians like myself will impose a particular axiomatic framework on BISH, but strictly speaking this is a departure from the intentions of the authors. Even in constructive reverse mathematics the base system is often unspecified.

Comment: @CarlMummert, could one ask such a question with regard to your axiomatisation?

Comment: @katz: you are right, there exists a second order axiomatization for BISH, but your question is about countable model, which needs a framework for model theory and I don't see any model theory framework for BISH. It is an axiomatization with intutionistic logic as underlying logic

Comment: @ErfanKhaniki, sticking to lower-level models, it would be interesting to establish in what constructive setting things like compactness, WKL, and LLPO are equivalent. There seems to be disagreement among editors in the comments above about what is needed here. One editor seems to think that this requires ZF, while another seems to think that a weaker system would suffice. I would appreciate any clarification.

Comment: Being a total ignorant of constructive mathematics, still it seems that any sort of "constructive NSA" would better be developed syntactically rather than model-theoretically, e.g. something like a baby-IST under intuitionistic logic

Comment: I don’t know the answer, I’m afraid; but unlike other commenters, I think this is a good and well-posed question.  Formal constructive reverse mathematics has been investigated by e.g. Ishihara, Nemoto, and colleagues, who have certainly considered what intuitionistic formal systems are required for equivalences between WKL, LLPO, and related principles; I have heard several conference talks by them on such issues, though I don’t remember their results precisely.  (cont’d)

Comment: On the other hand, while constructive model theory casts its net much wider than classical model theory (including Kripke models and much more), it certainly includes ordinary “Tarski” models as a special case of these.  So there is no problem with speaking of “compactness for (countable) (Tarski) models”.  The reason Tarski models are less-studied constructively isn’t because they’re problematic, it’s just that there may not exist enough of them for completeness, so one is forced (no pun intended) to look at more general kinds of models.

Comment: @Peter, thanks. It may make sense to convert these to an *answer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I share Vladimir Kanovei's view that the syntactical approach might be a good oppportunity to constructive NSA in much the same way as it was for  Nelson's Internal Set Theory.